# query to clone table gives error

Tags: sql, hsqldb, dbvisualizer

I am using the dbVisualizer to handle tables in my database, I want to clone a table. 
This is what I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE TIMEREPORT.MANAGER_CONFIRMATION_CRITERIA AS 
  (SELECT * FROM TIMEREPORT.MANAGER_CRITERIA);
```

But it gives me an error:

> 10:34:03  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -5590, SQL
>   State: 42590]  unexpected end of statement:  required: WITH

What am I missing?

Comment: SELECT * INTO TIMEREPORT.MANAGER_CONFIRMATION_CRITERIA FROM TIMEREPORT.MANAGER_CRITERIA; does not work either, expects FROM...INTO

Comment: dbVisualizer is not a DBMS. What's your database system? If this was a Teradata there must be WITH DATA or WITH NO DATA.

Comment: Do you want to create a table from an existing table with data?

Comment: You may have to create the table first, then do INSERT INTO "TIMEREPORT.MANAGER_CONFIRMATION_CRITERIA" SELECT * FROM "TIMEREPORT.MANAGER_CRITERIA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the Guide.

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_table_creation

You need to specify WITH DATA or WITH NO DATA at the end of the statement.